Can't send auditd log on RHEL 8 Linux to Qradar
I configured on RHEL 8 Server with auditd and rsyslog

/etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf

active = yes
direction = out
path = builtin_syslog
type = builtin
args = LOG_INFO LOG_LOCAL6
format = string


/etc/rsyslog.conf
local6.\*    @@QRADAR_CE_SERVER_IP:514
But nothing in Qradar and nothing in listen when I tcpdump
Please helpme with this issue
I checked /var/log/audit/audit.log => it's still logging
I've already created auditd rules

